# React Laravel api image upload image problem

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api

When I'm uploading the image. Laravel validation error is coming even though the image is input Image input field required

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB4bC.png)

code here I am providing only image field and state

AddProduct.jsx

```
  const [futureImg, setFutureImg] = useState([]);
  const [previewImg, setPreviewImg] = useState();

  const handleFutureImg = (e) => {

    setFutureImg({ image: e.target.files[0] });
    setPreviewImg(e.target.files[0]);

  }

  const productSubmitDB = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const productData = new FormData();
    productData.append('image', futureImg.image);

    axios.get(`/sanctum/csrf-cookie`).then((res) => {
      axios.post(`/api/store-product`, productData).then((res) => {
        if(res.data.status === 200){
          toast.success(res.data.message);
          navigate('/admin/all_product');
        }else{
          setErrors(res.data.validation_error);
        }
      })
    });
  }

  <form onSubmit={productSubmitDB} className="flex px-8 mt-8" encType='multipart/form-data'>
          <div className='bg-white border border-gray-300 mb-5 shadow-md rounded-t'>
            <div className='text-md text-gray-400 uppercase text-center py-2 border-b border-gray-300'>future image</div>
            <div className='py-8 flex flex-col px-3'>
              {previewImg && (
                <img className='rounded' src={URL.createObjectURL(previewImg)} alt="" />
              )}
              <label className='bg-red-400 cursor-pointer hover:bg-red-500 py-2 px-4 text-center mt-4 rounded-sm text-white capitalize transition duration-300' htmlFor="futureImage">upload</label>
              <input className='hidden' type="file" name='image' onChange={handleFutureImg} id="futureImage" />
              <span className='text-sm lowercase text-red-400 py-1'>{errors.image}</span>
            </div>
  </form>
```

laravel product model

```
protected $fillable = [
        'image',
    ];
}
```

laravel product controller

```
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'image' => 'required|mimes:png,jpeg,jpg,webp'
        ]);


        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $futureImage = $request->file('image');
            $extension = $futureImage->getClientoriginalExtension();
            $imageName = hexdec(uniqid()).'.'.$extension;
            $futureImage->move('upload', $imageName);
            $storePathDB = 'upload/'.$imageName;
        }

        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 401,
                'validation_error' => $validator->getMessageBag(),
            ]);
        }else{

            $product = new Product();
            $product->product_future_image      = $storePathDB;
            $product->save();

            return response()->json([
                'status' => 200,
                'message' => 'Product Add SuccessFull',
            ]);
        }
```

When I upload the image with postman it uploads successfully

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is not with the Laravel side, but rather with the React frontend. From the code provided, it appears that the problem might be due to how the FormData object is being constructed.

In the productSubmitDB function, you are using productData but it is not defined anywhere. You should create a FormData object and append the image to it. Also, make sure that the file input has the same name as expected in the backend.

Here's the modified productSubmitDB function:

```
const productSubmitDB = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Create a FormData object
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('image', futureImg.image);

  axios.get(`/sanctum/csrf-cookie`).then((res) => {
    axios.post(`/api/store-product`, formData).then((res) => {
      if(res.data.status === 200){
        toast.success(res.data.message);
        navigate('/admin/all_product');
      }else{
        setErrors(res.data.validation_error);
      }
    })
  });
}
```

Now, the frontend code should correctly send the image data to the backend, and you shouldn't face any validation errors when uploading an image.